# Weird "Dynamic Top Bar" bug every time I reboot/boot up

Tags: boot, themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, macbuntu

i'm using gnome flavour of ubuntu 16.10,with macbuntu theme and few gnome extensions. the problem i'm facing is activity text gets overlapped by the apple logo every time i start the computer. so every time i boot up i've to go to gnome tweak tool>extensions> dynamic top bar settings> enable and disable "show activity button text" option. and that solves the issue for that session. and it comes back when i reboot again

so my question is can i automate this action everytime i boot into my computer? or is their anything else i can do about this? or is their any other similar extension or app that i can use?

[image: Overlapping Activity Text on apple icon]

**UPDATE**
i tried the instructions in the answer but it's still not working

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep extensions
```

output

> org.gnome.shell.extensions.auto-move-windows
>   org.gnome.shell.extensions.screenshot-window-sizer
>   org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides
>   org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme
>   org.gnome.shell.extensions.native-window-placement
>   org.gnome.shell.extensions.window-list

**UPDATE 2**
the same problem is happening in another desktop with same setup

[Link to dynamic top bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/885/dynamic-top-bar/)

[Link to gtk theme that i'm using](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/11/macbuntu-1610-transformation-pack-for.html)

[Link to the source of the Extension](https://github.com/AMDG2/GnomeShell_DynamicTopBar)

**UPDATE 4**
Tried few other extensions, nothing works like dynamic top bar, is their a way that i could disable the `activity text` altogether

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. For everything that you can change in `gnome-tweak-tool` there is a corresponding `gsettings` command. The general syntax is:

`gsettings set SCHEMA [:PATH]  KEY VALUE`

You won't need the PATH parameter. Now what you should use as SCHEMA and KEY depends on the gnome-extension you want to use. First do

`gsettings list-schemas`

or perhaps

`gsettings list-schemas | grep extensions`

to find the correct schema. Then find the correct key with

`gsettings list-keys [SCHEMA]`

using the name you found in the previous step. The key will be something like `dynamic_top_bar_settings`. Then finally, do

`gsettings get [SCHEMA] [KEY]`

to see whether the dynamic top bar settings are enabled or disabled at this time; and do

`gsettings set [SCHEMA] [KEY] enabled`

to enable the setting.

Comment: thanks for the answer but, their is no command for dynamic top bar, i've tried both the commands

Comment: I'm looking into the source of the extension(https://github.com/AMDG2/GnomeShell_DynamicTopBar/releases), and there is a file called `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dynamic-top-bar.gschema.xml`.  Apparently, it doesn't work quite the way I thought.

Comment: so it can't be done?